AWS generate_presigned_url failing
I am trying to generate a pre-signed url in an AWS App Runner service. My s3 bucket is in us-east-2, and my app runner is also in us-east-2. I have ensured that my instance role has full access to S3. When calling the endpoint that calls generate_presigned_url:
aws_config = Config(
    region_name="us-east-2",
    signature_version="v4",
)

session = boto3.Session(region_name="us-east-2")

s3resource = session.resource("s3", config=aws_config)
s3client = session.client("s3", config=aws_config)

def generate_s3_presigned_url(bucket, key, expiration: int = 3600):
    """Geenerate a temporary url for an object.

    Args:
        bucket: The s3 bucket to sync from
        key: the key to generate a url for
    """
    signed_url = s3client.generate_presigned_url(
        "get_object",
        Params={"Bucket": bucket, "Key": key},
        ExpiresIn=expiration,
    )
    return signed_url

I am getting the error:
<Error>
<Code>AuthorizationQueryParametersError</Code>
<Message>Error parsing the X-Amz-Credential parameter; the region 'us-east-2' is wrong; expecting 'us-east-1'</Message>
<Region>us-east-1</Region>
<RequestId>xxxxx</RequestId>
<HostId>xxxxx</HostId>
</Error>```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!


I tried explicitly setting the region_name in the session. I also made sure that all of my env variables (AWS_DEFAULT_REGION, AWS_REGION) were set to us-east-2 in my docker file. Any help would be greatly appreciated!


Are you saying that this error happens when you try to use the returned URL? Or when your code calls s3client.generate_presigned_url(...)? Or some other time?

S3 is is specific service. Sometimes it behaves like regional service, other times like global one.
Try to remove region parameter from your S3 client. Connection will be created to default region for S3 (us-east-1).

The pre-signed URL operation doesn't generate credentials; it generates a pre-signed URL. It doesn't interact with the IAM or STS services; it simply uses your supplied AWS credentials to sign the URL.

Yes, you are right. I just removed this part from my answer
